# HTML data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: html, postgresql

Up to now I use the [Character Type "text"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) to store HTML in PostgreSQL.

I would like to make it more obvious to new users who look at the database schema, that this column contains HTML and not text.

How could I make this more obvious?

PS: I don't want PG to look into the HTML and validate it or quote it. This is just about users looking at the column specification and understanding "aha, this is html, not text".

Answer (score 4):

Postgres actually does have an XML type, but as HTML is not exactly XML, it may not make sense to use the XML type to store your content.

I suggest just putting the text `html` into the column name, e.g. something like `html_content`.  This way, it will be very visible to anyone perusing the table about what is contained within this column.